# How do I select specific index items from a multi-dimensional array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have the following multi-dimensional array:

```
var practice_times = [
    ['Tuesday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Thursday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Friday',['Mid Morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)']]
];
```

I want to be able to initially retrieve all the 'days', and place in a select element, then retrieve all the 'times' and place this in a different select element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - been scratching my head over this one for a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I forgot to mention that I had multiple (3) sets of days/times to deal with. This is the solution I came up with, prompted by some of your input:

```
/* Contact Form Setup */
var practice_times = [

  [
    ['Tuesday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Thursday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Friday',['Mid Morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)']]
  ],
  [
    ['Tuesday',['Early Afternoon (1-2.30pm)','Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)']]
  ],
  [
    ['Monday',['Mid-morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)','Early Afternoon (1-2.30pm)','Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)']],
    ['Tuesday',['Mid-morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)','Early Afternoon (1-2.30pm)','Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)']],
    ['Wednesday',['Mid-morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)','Early Afternoon (1-2.30pm)','Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)']],
    ['Thursday',['Mid-morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)','Early Afternoon (1-2.30pm)','Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)']],
    ['Friday',['Mid-morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)','Early Afternoon (1-2.30pm)','Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)']]
  ]                     
];

var getDays = function(index) {
    practiceIndex = index;
    days = [];
    for(var i in practice_times[index]) {
        days.push(practice_times[index][i][0]);
    }
    return days;
}

var getTimes = function(index) {
    times = practice_times[practiceIndex][index][1];
    return times;
}

var updateSelect = function(selectName,optArray) {
    //init options
    var selectOptions = "<option value='-'>- Preferred " + selectName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + selectName.substring(1) + " -</option>";
    //populate options
    for(var i=0; i < optArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(optArray[i][0]);
        selectOptions+= "<option>" + optArray[i] + "</option>";
    }
    //add options to select and show
    $('.contact-form select[name=' + selectName + ']').empty().append(selectOptions).show();
}

var toggleSelect = function(selectToToggle,selectVal) {
    selectToToggle.toggle(selectVal == '-' ? false : true);
}

//Initialise
var practiceIndex = -1;
$('.contact-form .day-time').hide();
$('.contact-form select[name=time]').hide();
//Select change events
$('.contact-form select[name=practice]').on('change',function(){ updateSelect('day',getDays($(this).prop('selectedIndex')-1)); toggleSelect($('.contact-form .day-time'),$(this).val()); });
$('.contact-form select[name=day]').on('change',function(){ updateSelect('time',getTimes($(this).prop('selectedIndex')-1)); toggleSelect($('.contact-form select[name=time]'),$(this).val()); });
```

Answer (score 0):

create 2 arrays and the fill the arrays as per your requirement..

```
var days = [],times= []
$.each(practice_times,function(index,value){
    days.push(value[0]);
    var objTime = value[1];
    times.push(objTime[0]);
    times.push(objTime[1]);
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var practice_times = [
    ['Tuesday', ['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)', 'Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Thursday', ['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)', 'Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Friday', ['Mid Morning (9am-12pm)', 'Midday (12-1pm)']]
];

//console.log(practice_times);

var day = [];
var Time = [];
for (var i in practice_times) {

    day.push(practice_times[i][0]);
    Time.push(practice_times[i][1]);
}
$("div:first").text(day);
$("div:eq(1)").text(Time);
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9pvea479/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<select class="day"></select>
<select class="time"></select>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var practice_times = [
    ['Tuesday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Thursday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Friday',['Mid Morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)']]
];
var day, time;
for(var i = 0; i < practice_times.length; i++){
    day = '<option value="'+practice_times[i][0]+'">'+practice_times[i][0]+'</option>';
    $('.day').append(day);
    time = '<option value="'+practice_times[i][1][0]+'">'+practice_times[i][1][0]+'</option>' +
        '<option value="'+practice_times[i][1][1]+'">'+practice_times[i][1][1]+'</option>';
    $('.time').append(time);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way

```
var text= new Object();
    text["a"] = "one";
    text["b"] = "two";

    for (key in text){
         console.log(text[key]);
         console.log(key);
    }
```

Using this you will get key and their value both, and also easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to create select options from your array :

```
 <select id='days'></select>
 <select id='time1'></select>
 <select id='time2'></select>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var practice_times = [
    ['Tuesday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Thursday',['Late Afternoon (2.30-5.30pm)','Evening (5.30-8.30pm)']],
    ['Friday',['Mid Morning (9am-12pm)','Midday (12-1pm)']]
   ];
   var i,j;
   var days,time1,time2='';  

   $.each(practice_times, function(key1, value1){

        var str = String(value1).split(","); 
         days += "<option>"+str[0] + "</option>";
         time1 += "<option>"+str[1]+ "</option>";
         time2 += "<option>"+str[2]+ "</option>";

   });
  $('#days').html(days);
  $('#time1').html(time1);
  $('#time2').html(time2);
```

});